# An excel file exported from an ArrayBuffer could not be opened in MS-Excel but is opened in Libre office

Tags: javascript, excel, xlsx, libreoffice

I have the following method that exports an excel file (.xlsx format) from an ArrayBuffer data and triggers a download.
The file downloaded opens fine in LibreOffice but fails in MS-Excel with this error.

Excel cannot open the file 'excelfile.xlsx' because the file format or file extension is not valid. Verify that the file has not been corrupted and that the file extension matches the format of the file.

```
export const downloadAs = (data, exportName, date = new Date(), extension = 'xlsx') => {
  const fileName = `${exportName}_${getDateTimeMmmDdYyyy(date)}.${extension}`;
  const blob = new Blob([data], { type: 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet' });
  saveAs(blob, fileName, true);
};
```

I expect the file to be opened in MS-Excel per my client's requirement.

Comment: It would help to see what your `data` looks like...

Comment: It's an ArrayBuffer of byteSize 10240
Here's a snippet:

[Int8Array]]: Int8Array(10240) [-48, -49, 17, -32, -95, -79, 26, -31, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, …]
[[Int16Array]]: Int16Array(5120) [-12336, -8175, -20063, -7910, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,  -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, …]
[[Int32Array]]: Int32Array(2560) [-535703600, -518344287, 0, 0, 0, 0, 196667, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, …]
[[Uint8Array]]: Uint8Array(10240) [208, 207, 17, 224, 161,0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 59, 0, 3, 0, 254, 255, 9, 0,

Comment: Have you tried saving the file as .csv instead of .xlsx? Can't really tell from the ArrayBuffer whether that's valid XLSX format